# React Native app crashes when opened on Test Pilot

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, app-store-connect

My React Native app successfully builds and uploads to App Store Connect, but it crashes when I try to open it on TestFlight. Works locally on simulator though.

**Error Message**

> yardenMobile: facebook::react::RCTNativeModule::invoke(unsigned int,
> folly::dynamic&&, int)::$_0::operator()() const + 68

[Full Error Logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V7UaO.png)

This error message is indicating an issue in an implementation of the Facebook React Native framework. The error message specifically mentions "RCTNativeModule::invoke", which refers to a function within the framework that's used to call native modules from JavaScript. The message is indicating that there is an issue within this function, in the code located at the "+ 68" offset.

Here is my react-native info:

```
System:
    OS: macOS 13.0
    CPU: (8) arm64 Apple M1
    Memory: 77.06 MB / 8.00 GB
    Shell: 5.8.1 - /bin/zsh
  Binaries:
    Node: 16.17.0 - ~/.nvm/versions/node/v16.17.0/bin/node
    Yarn: 1.22.19 - /usr/local/bin/yarn
    npm: 8.15.0 - ~/.nvm/versions/node/v16.17.0/bin/npm
    Watchman: 2021.10.04.00 - /opt/homebrew/bin/watchman
  Managers:
    CocoaPods: 1.11.2 - /opt/homebrew/bin/pod
  SDKs:
    iOS SDK:
      Platforms: DriverKit 22.1, iOS 16.1, macOS 13.0, tvOS 16.1, watchOS 9.1
    Android SDK: Not Found
  IDEs:
    Android Studio: Not Found
    Xcode: 14.1/14B47b - /usr/bin/xcodebuild
  Languages:
    Java: Not Found
  npmPackages:
    @react-native-community/cli: Not Found
    react: 17.0.2 => 17.0.2 
    react-native: 0.66.0 => 0.66.0 
    react-native-macos: Not Found
  npmGlobalPackages:
    *react-native*: Not Found
```

Anyone know how I can possibly fix this?

WHAT I TRIED
I tried opening the app on TestPilot, but it crashed

WHAT I EXPECTED
I expected the app to open on TestPilot successfully

Comment: your questions lack of informations, include your package.json, try with minimum build, start adding one by one library or screen to see which code cause the failure.

Comment: if you run expo doctor does it recommend to update the version of any packages that you are using?